# Multiple textures with SOIL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to load 2 texture at the same time into my fragment shader:

```
in vec2 TexCoord;
layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;

void main() {
    FragColor = mix(texture(tex1, TexCoord),texture(tex2, TexCoord), 0.3);
}
```

I'm using SOIL library to do this:

```
GLuint tex1 = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("rock.bmp", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                                SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
GLuint tex2 = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("lena512.bmp", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                                SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
```

However only the second texture is showing up, not the first one. I realize that  I need to perform glUniform1i somewhere attaching sampler2D tex1 to the first one and vice versa. How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nearly impossible to explain because of the `mix` operation. If you want to debug this properly, remove that and try with `FragColor = texture (tex1, TexCoord);` and `FragColor = texture (tex2, TexCoord);`. Whichever of those two variations produces a solid color, that's the texture unit that doesn't have anything bound to it.

My guess is that the **uniform** `tex1` (**0** by default) has the second texture you loaded.

SOIL will bind the texture to the currently active texture unit, so consider something like this instead:

```
glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0);
GLuint tex1 = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("rock.bmp", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                                    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);

glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE1);
GLuint tex2 = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("lena512.bmp", SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                                    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
```

Now `tex1` will be bound to **0** and `tex2` will be bound to **1**. Also consider using different names for textures and samplers, this whole thing is confusing because it's never clear whether you're talking about `tex1` in the C code or `tex1` in the GLSL code ;)

Comment: Thanks! I followed your approach and the second sampler is loaded with the first texture. Is there any other binding necessary?

Comment: Nvm, I need to use glUniform1i and glGetUniformLocation to set the connection between sampler2D and textures.